# Background image allow to overflow out of a input button

Tags: css

I need to achieve below green tick when i select the Yes or no button

[image]

I have tried giving the right tick as back-ground image on my button and it is getting trimmed after the button

CSS for it -->

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8C16 12.4183 12.4183 16 8 16C3.58172 16 0 12.4183 0 8C0 3.58172 3.58172 0 8 0C12.4183 0 16 3.58172 16 8Z' fill='%23137E84'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M4.18587 7.42171C4.43369 7.17468 4.83549 7.17468 5.08331 7.42171L6.8782 9.21085L10.9167 5.18527C11.1645 4.93824 11.5663 4.93824 11.8141 5.18527C12.062 5.4323 12.062 5.83282 11.8141 6.07985L6.8782 11L4.18587 8.31628C3.93804 8.06925 3.93804 7.66874 4.18587 7.42171Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-position: right -7px top -7px;
```

[image]

I have also tried giving the right tick as background image on outer div - then it gets trimmed on  button with below CSS on out div of button

```
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg  width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8C16 12.4183 12.4183 16 8 16C3.58172 16 0 12.4183 0 8C0 3.58172 3.58172 0 8 0C12.4183 0 16 3.58172 16 8Z' fill='%23137E84'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M4.18587 7.42171C4.43369 7.17468 4.83549 7.17468 5.08331 7.42171L6.8782 9.21085L10.9167 5.18527C11.1645 4.93824 11.5663 4.93824 11.8141 5.18527C12.062 5.4323 12.062 5.83282 11.8141 6.07985L6.8782 11L4.18587 8.31628C3.93804 8.06925 3.93804 7.66874 4.18587 7.42171Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: right 5px top 5px;
        overflow: visible;
```

[image]

Tried fiddling around with Z index as well - but no luck there as such.

Any hints/help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _"and it is getting trimmed after the button"_ - so the fact that the _background_ of an element can't extend further than the element's dimensions, actually surprised you? _"Tried fiddling around with Z index as well - but no luck there as such."_ - can't tell you what is going on, based on just a few lines of CSS on their own. Provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `:after` element which you can place in the top right corner using `position: absolute;`

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div');
Array.from(buttons).forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.classList.toggle('checked')));
```

```css
.button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

.checked:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg  width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M16 8C16 12.4183 12.4183 16 8 16C3.58172 16 0 12.4183 0 8C0 3.58172 3.58172 0 8 0C12.4183 0 16 3.58172 16 8Z' fill='%23137E84'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='M4.18587 7.42171C4.43369 7.17468 4.83549 7.17468 5.08331 7.42171L6.8782 9.21085L10.9167 5.18527C11.1645 4.93824 11.5663 4.93824 11.8141 5.18527C12.062 5.4323 12.062 5.83282 11.8141 6.07985L6.8782 11L4.18587 8.31628C3.93804 8.06925 3.93804 7.66874 4.18587 7.42171Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
    right: -12px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>FooBar</div>
<br />
<div class='button checked'>FooBar</div>
```

Comment: thank you, that's perfect position , but am still not able to get it on click of button , when i user after - it comes by default, i need the icon once i click on the button

Comment: I'll update my answer, gimme sec

Comment: Done, please press the button to `toggle` the `checked` class and the icon will (dis)appear.

Comment: Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.